# How to show FloatingActionButton on top of the bottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show `FloatingActionButton` on top of the `BottomNavigationBar`. I have created two separate widgets for `FloatingActionButton` and `BottomNavigationBar`.  But when i replace the `FloatingActionButton` on the screen it will be behind the `BottomNavigationBar`

> please see below image

[image]

Please find the following code snippets. I want to show the `FloatingActionButton` on top of the `bottomNavigationBar`.

main_screen.dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: Header().build(context),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(this._onItemTapped, _selectedIndex)],
        );
  }
```

bottomNavBar.dart

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onItemTapped;
  final int selectedIndex;

  BottomNavBar(this.onItemTapped,this.selectedIndex);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BottomNavBar();
  }
}

class _BottomNavBar extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: widget.selectedIndex,
        items: navigationItems,
        onTap: (index) {
          widget.onItemTapped(index);
        },
        fixedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color,
        iconSize: 24.0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed);
  }

}
```

floatingActionButton.dart

The `FloatingActionButton` is inside a `Stack` layout and its called inside a `BottomNavigationBarItem` (this is an another screen)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: expandedSize,
      height: expandedSize,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildExpandedBackground(),
              _buildFabCore()
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget _buildFabCore() {
        double scaleFactor = 2 * (_animationController.value - 0.5).abs();
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _onFabTap,
          child: Transform(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(1.0, scaleFactor),
            child: Icon(
                _animationController.value > 0.5 ? Icons.close : Icons.filter_list,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 26),
          ),
          backgroundColor: _colorAnimation.value,
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `Scaffold` add property `floatingActionButtonLocation` to `FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,` or `FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked`.

`endFloat` will add FAB above bottom nav. Try applying both.

**Edit(an example):**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter GTranslate Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054289/pexels-photo-1054289.jpeg",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.red,),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 4.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.person),
                    Text("Profile"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    Text("Favorite"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.settings),
                    Text("Settings"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 6.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Icon(Icons.menu),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working. The `FloatingActionButton` is inside a `Stack` layout and its called inside a `BottomNavigationBarItem` (another screen)

Comment: @AmilaDulanjana See, You havent mentioned anything like that. So, how can I know what is your problem and how you have tried. Please update your question with description and with relevant code snippets.

Comment: I updated the question. Please now can you give me an answer ?

Comment: I dont know what you are going to achive by Stack(scenario I mean). And how above snippets combine but I have added a simple example that you can use. But keep remember even my example source different than the way you wanted, you can do what you want by wrapping bottom nav with another stack widget.